# remove mapedit features programmatically

Tags: r, shiny, r-sf, r-leaflet

With `mapedit` it is possible to clear drawn features using the 'trash' icon built into the drawbar UI. It is also possible to clear features associated with the leaflet map using `clearMarkers()` and `leafletProxy()`, as laid out in [this issue](https://github.com/r-spatial/mapedit/issues/61). However, leafletProxy does not clear any features drawn by the user. How do I programmatically clear these features? (e.g. after clicking an actionButton).

Here is a simple shiny app and more explanation:

```
library(mapedit)
library(mapview)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    editModUI("editor"),
    actionButton('clear', "Clear features")
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  edits <- callModule(editMod, "editor", mapview()@map)

  observeEvent(input$clear, {
    ### some other things will happen here like uploading dropbox
    # then I need to clear the output of edits()
    print(edits())

    ##cannot do this
    # edits()$drawn <- NULL
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

UPDATE: A somewhat hacky solution is to call the module again within the clear event. Is there a better solution?:

```
 server <- function(input, output, session) {

  edits <- callModule(editMod, "editor", mapview()@map)

  observeEvent(input$clear, {
    ### some other things will happen here like uploading dropbox
      edits <- callModule(editMod, "editor", mapview()@map)
  })
}
```